Proving that Euclidean Jordan algebra automorphisms are orthogonal symmetric cone automorphisms
Recall the setting of,

Jacques Faraut and Adam Korányi. Analysis on Symmetric Cones. Clarendon Press, Oxford, 1994. ISBN 9780198534778.

Namely, suppose that,

$\left(V,\circ,\left<\cdot,\cdot\right>\right)$ is a Euclidean Jordan algebra
$Aut\left(V\right)$ is the group of Jordan-algebra automorphisms on $V$
$O\left(V\right)$ is the group of isometries on $V$ with respect to $\left<\cdot,\cdot\right>$
$\Omega$ is the symmetric cone of squares in $V$
$G\left(\Omega\right)$ is the linear automorphism group of the cone $\Omega$, i.e. the set of all invertible linear $L : V \to V$ such that $L\left(\Omega\right) = \Omega$.
$L_{x}$ is the linear operator $y \mapsto x \circ y$
$\operatorname{tr}\left(x\right)$ is the sum of the Jordan-algebraic eigenvalues of $x$

When $V$ is simple, it's relatively easy to show that $Aut\left(V\right) = G\left(\Omega\right) \cap O\left(V\right)$. See Theorem 8 in Gowda's Positive and doubly stochastic maps, and majorization in Euclidean Jordan algebras, for example. When $V$ is not simple, we have only a remark at the top of Faraut and Korányi's page 57 suggesting that the result holds if the inner product is given by either $\left<x,y\right> = \operatorname{trace}\left(L_{x \circ y}\right)$ or $\left<x,y\right> = \operatorname{tr}\left(x \circ y\right)$.
Is a proof of the general case known? I've never been able to find one.
Edit:
I've posted a preprint where I prove this result as a side effect of characterizing the inner products for which the desired identity holds. (In particular, we see that it holds for the two inner products mentioned in the original question.)

Michael Orlitzky. Jordan and isometric cone automorphisms in Euclidean Jordan algebras. Preprint, November 24, 2024.

